# Find minimum at each index after queries

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

Suppose that you are given an array of known length `N` which is initialized to infinity.

Queries of the form `(L,R,Val)` are activated such that `0 <= L <= R <= N-1`. Each query updates the array such that

```
for all i in [L, R]
  array[i] = min(Val, array[i])
```

For example:

Initialization: `N = 5` - array is `{inf, inf, inf, inf, inf}`

Query 1: `(1, 3, 6)` - array get converted into `{inf, 6, 6, 6, inf}`.
Query 2: `(2, 4, 2)` - array get converted into `{inf, 6, 2, 2, 2}`.

**Requirement:** After all queries, find the value at each element index.

Considering above array with name of arr then-
`arr[0] = inf` ,`arr[1] = 6`, `arr[2] = 2`...

To tackle this question, I have the following ideas:

1. Brute force approach (Take each query and update the array).
2. Segment tree (with or without lazy propagation).

Is there any other way to solve this problem (like with the help of sqrt decomposition or using other data structure, like a stack or queue) to solve it linearly or with better complexity.

Comment: Please show your code attempt to solve the problem

Comment: "such that value of array elements in given range is minimum." --- do you mean that your `Val` parameter of the request is always smaller that all the elements in the given range?

Comment: Very vague. Please rewrite your  question to make it clear

Comment: @petr it means that value of array elements must be minimum after each update operation

Comment: @sameer can you please tell which part is not clear so that I can elaborate on that??

Comment: Let's say that there are M querries. Then the naive way to calculate the final result for every arr[i] (0 <= i < N) is to go through all the M querries. This is of time complexity O(M * N).

The question is whether this is good enough for you ... what will be the approximate size of M and N?

Comment: Would be more interesting with a 3rd querry `(2, 3, some_value_between2and6like3)`.

Comment: What are the ranges of `N`, `L`, `R`, `Val`?

Comment: Whatsup @chux this question was asked in interview so there was no explicit definition of limits.. to solve this better we can define limits such as N < 10^6  Val < 10^9

Comment: @user3703826 Note: As an interview question, often it is not the answer that is sought, but the approach to the task - which includes understanding the requirements like range of inputs, preciseness, schedule, platform, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can solve this problem in this way.

`Event is structure which consist boolean start/finish, value and coordinate
Every query transform in two events. For example query L:1 R:5 VAL: 10 transform in event TRUE 10 1 and event FALSE 10 5 
than sort all events by coordinate value
next go through events and maintain current minimum and fill array
You can maintain minimum with a lot of different data structures( for example you can use map in CPP)`

Complexity of this solution is O(M log M+(N+M) log M)
where M is number of queries and N is number of elements